# Patching function from a dict of callbacks mocks it, but does not register invocations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a dict of keys -> callbacks and want to test that the right callback is being invoked with the appropriate arguments. I'm patching out the method and asserting it is called, however it isn't working as expected. It is raising an assertion error.

However, if I replace the variable holding the callback with the function itself, it is working. The debugger states the callback is equal to the function being mocked. So it seems as if setting the function to a variable and invoking it that way does not register as calling the function itself.

Here is the code that I'd expect to work:

```
#failing_processor.py
from .x import handle_x_command
from .y import handle_y_command

COMMANDS = {
    'X': handle_x_command,
    'Y': handle_y_command,
}           

def parse_command_and_arguments(command_line):
    command_arguments = command_line.split()
    command_key, arguments = command_arguments[0], command_arguments[1:]
    command = COMMANDS[command_key] #Gets the handle_x_command callback
    return command, arguments


def process_commands():
    for command_line in ['X arg1 arg2']: #Hard coded to force an X command
        command, arguments = parse_command_and_arguments(command_line)
        print(f'COMMAND {command}')
        command(drivers, *arguments) #Invoke the callback. This is what i'm testing
```

```
#test.py
from mock import patch

from . import processor


def test_driver_handler_called():
    with patch('processor.processor.handle_x_command') as mock_handle_x_command:   
        processor.process_commands() 
        mock_handle_x_command.assert_called() #This fails
```

This prints `COMMAND <function handle_x_command at 0x###>`, which shows the command is equal to `handle_x_command`. But the assert_called fails.

If I replace the variable command with the actual function, it passes as expected

```
#passing_processor.py
def process_commands():
    for command_line in ['X arg1 arg2']:
        command, arguments = parse_command_and_arguments(command_line)
        handle_x_command(drivers, *arguments) #This works
```

Is there a way I can assert the command is the callback I'm expecting it to be? I've manually tested and the logic works as expected, and it's printing that command is equal to what I'd expect, so it seems to be a weird edge case that I can't find documentation for handling.

---

Update:

It looks like the issue is it being in a global variable. The real handle_x_command function is set to the dict. *Then* the patches happen. However, it doesn't retroactively patch the global `COMMANDS` dict. So the function is mocked, but the dict is the real function. So when it is called, the real function is invoked instead of the mock. However, reloading the module after the patch doesn't keep the patch around. If I could delay setting the `COMMAND` variable until *after* the patch happens, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overwriting each of the handlers after I patched them in each test. I wish there was a better "automatic" way to do this, but this does in fact work:

```
def set_command_mocks(mock_handle_x_command, mock_handle_y_command):
    # Overwrite the commands with mock commands
    processor.COMMANDS['X'] = mock_handle_x_command
    processor.COMMANDS['Y'] = mock_handle_y_command


@patch('processor.processor.handle_y_command')
@patch('processor.processor.handle_x_command')
def test_x_handler_called(mock_handle_x_command, mock_handle_y_command):
    set_command_mocks(mock_handle_x_command, mock_handle_y_command)

    processor.process_commands(None)

    mock_handle_x_command.assert_called_with('Test')
    assert not mock_handle_y_command.called
```

It works because the patch happens, we get the mocked functions, and then we set the dict's values manually. Again, I wish there was a better way to do this, but this does in fact work. The big downside is you have to manually do it every time for every different dict key. I feel like there could be mistakes when you manually rewrite the callbacks to the mocked callbacks.